# Lagrange theorem- demonstration

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Would you help me demonstrate with  Lagrange's theorem that

$$\sin x < x < \tan x \quad\text{for }x\in \left(0,\frac{\pi}2\right)$$

I am not so advanced in mathematics, we haven't seen this theorem in class, so I really start from nothing.

Comment: By "Lagrange's theorem" do you mean his version of the Mean Value Theorem? There are many ways to prove your desired statement, including geometric--you can't use another method?

Comment: This depends on your definition of $\sin x$ and $\tan x$.

Comment: No I can't use an other method. I haven't had any more infos. And I never heard about the mean value theorem...

Answer (score 3):

[image: unit circle]

Consider the unit circle above.  It is clear that the area of triangle $OAB$ is greater than the area of sector $OAC$ which is greater than the area of triangle $OAC$.

What is the area of triangle $OAB$?  $\frac{1}{2}(1)(\tan(x))$.

What is the area of sector $OAC$? $\frac{1}{2}(1^{2})(x)$

What is the area of triangle $OAC$? $\frac{1}{2}(1)(\sin(x))$

The desired inequality follows.

Comment: This is a nice proof but it seems the OP wanted a proof using the mean value theorem. I've upvoted it anyway because it's a nice way to geometrically see why this should be the case.

Comment: Good call.  I had never heard the MVT called "Lagrange's theorem", so I figured sin(x) < x < tan(x) was Lagrange's theorem.  I didn't read the question closely enough!

Comment: It's definitely far from a standard use of the term. I don't blame you. Don't delete your answer though. It's one of the more elegant answers I've seen for these.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start of one proof using the Mean Value Theorem. Use the fact that for $x\in \left(0,\frac{\pi}2\right)$,

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin x<1=\frac{d}{dx}x<\frac{d}{dx}\tan x$$

Then look at the interval between $0$ and $x$ using the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: not a proof....

Comment: @ProbabilityGuy: What do you mean? If the inequalities in my answer are given, they can be combined with the Mean Value Theorem to give a proof. I said what I wrote was a start... not the whole proof.

Comment: I dont get what you are saying but still this is not a proof