# Limits of Rolle theorem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, examples-counterexamples, rolles-theorem

I would like to see a function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable in $(a,b)$ but it is not continuous at least at one of the interval boundary points $a$ or $b$. Can you show me one?

This is a curiosity that would make me to see limits of Rolle theorem, because one of its hypothesis is that the function $f$ has to be continuous in the entire closed interval $[a,b]$, even if it could be differentiable only in the open $(a,b)$.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The first phrase. I edit to make the question clearer.

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear: "why can we not relax the requirement of continuity on $[a,b]$ in Rolle's theorem?".

Comment: @PatrickStevens I was truly unsure what the OP was intending to ask. The reply to my comment made even less sense. I am not sure how you have the ability to read peoples minds through what they write, but OK.

Comment: I can not understand how my simple answer "the first sentence is my question" could not make sense, but OK.

Comment: Essentially if $f$ is not continuous at both $a$ and $b$ then knowing $f(a)=f(b)$ is not helpful information.  But you need that to avoid strictly monotonic functions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = x$ on $(0, 1]$, and $f(0) = 1$.

Comment: Who knows for what obscure reason I was imagining things incredibly more complex than that. Thank you very much. Sorry for the question that now seems very stupid to me.

Comment: In first-year analysis, there are about five different counterexamples, all of them quite simple. Almost nothing you'll encounter will require really pathological counterexamples.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ in $[0, 1]$ and define $f(0) = 0.5$.

Then by the extreme value theorem - which is needed to make Rolle's Theorem work - since $f$ doesn't obtain a maximum, $f$ is not continuous on $[a,b]$.